# Add search command to windows startmenu

Tags: windows, search, command, startmenu

How can I add a command like the "Search the Internet" command in the windows startmenu.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpWEz.png

Something like "Search the Wiki" so that my Browser-Website would be called with the given search parameters.
I don't want to show results directly in the starmenu...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

The Windows Shell team has, for several releases now, restricted ways of extending things because it has been so terribly abused in the past. Imagine opening your start menu and seeing a dozen different search providers there that all got installed because they can.

If this is for your personal use you can just create a program or batch file that does what you need with its arguments, then you could just type something like `w foo` and have it open a browser with “the Wiki” (whichever you mean) searching for “foo”.

A somewhat broken such batch file could be

```
@echo off
set "s=%*"
start "" "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%s: =+%"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This information was what I was looging for.